# How to disable hot-pluggable CPU on ARM?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, embedded, arm

I have an ARM64 Cortex-A72 board running Linux 5.4.47. I want to check if the CPU hot-plugging is working correctly (it's needed for one project I want to use).

Kernel has `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU` enabled, but I don't have `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online` for any CPU - **and I don't know how I could turn off a CPU**.

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu]# ls -l
total 0
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 consumers
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 cpu0
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 cpu1
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 cpu2
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 cpu3
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 cpuidle
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 hotplug
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 isolated
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 kernel_max
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 modalias
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 nohz_full
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:13 offline
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 online
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 possible
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 power
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 present
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 smt
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 suppliers
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:00 uevent
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:00 vulnerabilities
```

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2]# ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:07 cache
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:06 consumers
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:06 cpu_capacity
-r--------    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:06 crash_notes
-r--------    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:06 crash_notes_size
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:06 hotplug
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:06 node0 -> ../../node/node0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:06 of_node -> ../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/cpus/cpu@2
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:06 power
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:12 regs
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:06 subsystem -> ../../../../bus/cpu
-r--r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:06 suppliers
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jan  1 00:03 topology
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  1 00:06 uevent
```

The `hotplug` contains files `target`, `state` and `fail`. The `power` contains `runtime_active_time`, `pm_qos_resume_latency_us`, `runtime_status`, `autosuspend_delay_ms`, `runtime_suspended_time` and `control`.